# Combined CSS declaration in wordpress

Tags: css, css-selectors

In WordPress, it uses li to declare the menu item, what is the difference between two CSS declaration `#navigator > li` and `#navigator li`?

Comment: I can't decide which of the 10k questions about direct descendant selectors this one is duplicate of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is not *In WordPress*, but is a CSS selector behavior:

The white space is a [**Descendant Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) that, by definition

> matches only those elements matching the second selector for which there is an ancestor element matching the first selector. Descendant selectors are similar to child selectors, but they do not require that the relationship between matched elements be strictly parent-child.

In your case, `#navigator li` will match all `li` at any nested level inside `#navigator`.

Example:

```
<ul id="#navigator">
    <li> <!-- this is selected -->
        <div>
           <ul>
               <li> <!-- this is selected -->
```

**On the other hand**

The `>` is a [**Child Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), that:

> matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first.

In your case, `#navigator > li` will match only `li` that are direct childs of `#navigator`.

Example:

```
<ul id="#navigator">
    <li> <!-- only this is selected -->
        <div>
           <ul>
               <li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between those 2 is that the > selector (`#navigator > li`) means the immediate child and the `#navigator li` means all the `li` that have as ancestor the `#navigator`.